# How can I decode the feature string of a Lightning node with BOLT #9?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, lightning-rfc

Typing the following command *(with a running lightningd)*:

```
 lightning-cli listpeers
```

I get peers which all have a `features` flag, for example `0252a1`. In the manpage `lightning-listpeers(7)` it says, that it corresponds to the features mentioned in BOLT #9.

How do I get from `0252a1` to the features listed in the table seen in the [BOLT #9 document](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/09-features.md)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit is a **b**inary dig**it** with the two possible expressions 0 and 1. Binary data is often represented as hexadecimal in writing as that is more compact and human-readable. Hexadecimal (base 16) encodes the (decimal) numbers 0 through 15 with the symbols 0-9 and A-F (where A-F represent 10-15).

A few examples (subscript indicates base):
1<sub>10</sub> = 1<sub>16</sub> = 0001<sub>2</sub>
5<sub>10</sub> = 5<sub>16</sub> = 0101<sub>2</sub>
10<sub>10</sub> = A<sub>16</sub> = 1010<sub>2</sub>
13<sub>10</sub> = D<sub>16</sub> = 1101<sub>2</sub>

The flag array that you quote, `0252a1` would translate to the binary array `100101001010100001`

To use it as a flag array, we do not interpret it as a number but interpret a 1 as a feature being set and a 0 as a feature being unset. We refer to each bit by its position counting from the rightmost. The rightmost is the zeroth bit and even.

The [Feature Flags (BOLT #9)](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/09-features.md) in Lightning are always assigned in pairs. Even bits refer to features that our node will consider mandatory, odd bits refer to optional features our node supports. Other nodes will ignore odd bits that they don't understand ("It's okay to be odd."), but will disconnect if there are even bits set they don't support.

`1001010010101000_01_`
Bits 0/1 refer to the feature `option_data_loss_protect`. The flag is on the even bit (the 0th), thus the feature is mandatory.

`10010100101010_00_01`
Bits 2/3 refer to `initial_routing_sync`. Since neither bit is set, our node does not support that feature.

`100101001010_10_0001`
Bits 4/5 signal `option_upfront_shutdown_script`. The flag is on bit 5, and thus it's an optional feature.

`1001010010_10_100001`
Bits 6/7 signal `gossip_queries`. The flag is on bit 7, also optional.

`10010100_10_10100001`
Bits 8/9 signal `var_onion_optin`. As the flag is on the odd bit, it's an optional feature.

`100101_00_1010100001`
Bits 10/11 is for `gossip_queries_ex`. Our node does not support this feature.

`1001_01_001010100001`
Bits 12/13 indicate that `option_static_remotekey` is mandatory for this node's peers, as it is set on bit 12, the even bit.

`10_01_01001010100001`
Bits 14/15 refer to `payment_secret` which is also mandatory.

`_10_0101001010100001`
The flag on bit 17 indicates that `basic_mpp` is optional.

The absence of the feature flags on bits 18-27 indicates that the node does not recognize any of the corresponding features.